# yfinance doens't download and also gives no error

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, yfinance

I wrote a script on my laptop and tried it at home on my pc. It works on the laptop but when running on the pc, the script runs but doesn't return anything. It also doesn't show an error.

It is a very simple script to download the stock data of apple:

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf

print('start')
ticker = "AAPL"
df = yf.download(ticker, period="max")
print('middle')
df.to_csv(f"./Data/{ticker}.csv")
print('end')
```

Can you tell me what the reason is that nothing is being downloaded?

I run it on my laptop with a venv (Python 3.11.1) and on my pc with a venv (Python 3.11.2)
yfinance version 0.2.27

I added the print commands to see where it breaks. The first gets executed. the rest not.

edit: I work with VSCode. I tried to run it in an interactive window to figure out if I get any data from the download and the whole script ran without a problem! I now tried it again with "run python file" and it still doesn't work.

Comment: When you say "the first gets executed" is that the imports working, or the df correctly downloading or what. Is the `df` correctly filled in with the data?

Comment: I added an edit to the question as I checked with the interactive window in vscode if I get data. I do get data and it gets saved (everything works fine if executed as an interactive window but still doesn't work with the normal "run python file"

Comment: Are you sure your interractive window uses the same python version (/venv) as your .py script?

Comment: it says so, yes

Comment: Have you tried debug mode? Is there any error report?

Comment: I changed to python 3.10. Now it works

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT I wrote on github/vscode and they adviced me to run it in the terminal to see if it is a vscode problem. The terminal gave the same result, it therefore has to be the yfinance version that doesn't work with 3.11 properly. On the pypi page it says 3.4+ but on the left side he doesn't mention 3.10. That's why I think 3.11 is not yet supported. Thank you for your input!

Comment: The issue is solved. The anti-virus software interrupted the process. The problem no longer exists after whitelisting the folder. thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved. The anti-virus software interrupted the process. The problem no longer exists after whitelisting the folder. thank you for your help.